# Set the output text of a button to a certain font

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-fonts

I am making a keyboard app (general purpose, not just for a specific textview). Currently when the user presses a key the following code happens:

```
getCurrentInputConnection().commitText("string",1);
```

Is there anyway I can set the font of the input string? That way if the user presses the button instead of sending a message with the default font it will send it with a custom font.

Comment: Could someone explain why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set the font of a string, but you usually can set the font of the containing object which will display the string